# Changing a method that has "return" and "yield return"

Tags: c#, return, yield-return

I know it's impossible to use `return` and `yield return` in the same method.

This is the code that I would like to optimize:

```
public IEnumerable<TItem> GetItems(int data)
{
    if (this.isSingleSet)
    {
        return this.singleSet; // is IEnumerable per-se
    }
    else
    {
        int index = this.GetSet(data);
        foreach(TKey key in this.keySets[index])
        {
            yield return this.items[key];
        }
    }
}
```

**Important:** I know this code **doesn't compile**. It's the code I have to optimize.

There are two ways that I know of that would make this method working:

1. convert `yield return` part:

   ```
   ...
   else
   {
       int index = this.GetSet(data);
       return this.keySets[index].Select(key => this.items[key]);
   }
   ```
2. convert `return` part:

   ```
   if (this.isSingleSet)
   {
       foreach(TItem item in this.singleSet)
       {
           yield return item;
       }
   }
   else ...
   ```

But there's a big speed difference between the two. Using only `return` statements (in other words using `Select()`) is much much slower (like 6 times slower) to `yield return` conversion.

### Question

Is there any other way that comes to your mind how to write this method? Do you have any other suggestions information that would be valuable to performance discrepancy?

### Additional info

I was measuring speed of the two methods by using stopwatch around a `for` loop.

```
Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
s.Start();
for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    GetItems(GetRandomData()).ToList();
}
s.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(s.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Each of these were loops were run in separate processes so there was could be no performance influence by garbage collection or anything else.

1. I've run the program with one method version then
2. Closed it
3. Rewrote the method and run it again.

Did this few times to see reliable performance difference...

Comment: My vote is #1. Have you done actual testing to see that it is slower?

Comment: Could you post the piece of code that you used to evaluate the relative speed of the two methods?

Comment: Are you sure _yield return_ is faster ? If you measured, remember to enumerate the enumerable returned - if you don't, you will get a small execution time due to deferred execution. (In other words, what to do might depend on whether you will always need ALL of the items returned, or in some cases only some of the items from the beginning of the returned collection).

Comment: Yes. Executing these two methods a million times with same test data shows a **6 fold** performance gain when I use `foreach` statements.

Comment: @driis: I've edited my question a bit to add some more info. Yes I did performance testing of both and as you can see by the provided code I'm iterating resulting enumerable by calling `ToList()`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use *two* functions. The outer, called by clients, function does all the non-lazy bits (like parameter validation) that you don't want to delay. The private worker does the lazy bits:

```
public IEnumerable<TItem> GetItems(int data) {
  if (this.isSingleSet) {
    return this.singleSet; // is IEnumerable per-se
  } else {
    return DoGetItems(data);
  }
}

private IEnumerable<TItem> DoGetItems(int data) {
  int index = this.GetSet(data);
  foreach(TKey key in this.keySets[index]) {
    yield return this.items[key];
  }
}
```

Comment: Great idea! I don't know why didn't I thought of this one!

Comment: @RobertKoritnik It is an obvious approach – once you have seen it (I can't recall now when I saw it, but it lead to a significant amount of rewrite to allow parameter validation in helpers to be done eagerly while the result was lazy).

Comment: Of course it is. I was obviously thinking too much about complex solutions not to see the most obvious one... **Extracting a method.**

Answer (score 5):

The implementation of Select is (with the error checking removed):

```
public static IEnumerable<R> Select<A, R>(
    this IEnumerable<A> sequence, 
    Func<A, R> projection)
{
    foreach(A item in sequence) 
        yield return projection(item);
}
```

So I have a hard time believing that your using Select is *hugely* slower than the almost-identical foreach loop you already have. It will be slowed down by doing error checking (once) and by creating the delegate (once), and the slight overhead of indirecting through the delegate. But the loop machinery should be identical.

However, if I've learned one thing in performance analysis, it's that my expectations are frequently dead wrong. What does your profiling run indicate is the bottleneck in your application? Let's reason from facts, not from guesses here. What is the hot spot?

Comment: Well Eric you'+re missing the main thing here. The problem is **projection** because compiled code shows that `GetItems` method instantiates a new `Func<T1, T2>` on each call. This instantiation is the main performance killer when using `Select` with lambda. Or so it seems. Because the manual `foreach` obviously doens't use anything similar.

Comment: And just to make it clear: my performance measurements are strictly done on this method call. I will be calling it many times in production so I wanted to test speed difference of both versions.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik: are you *sure* that the delegate is re-allocated? I am not in my office today so I can't check the compiled code, but that lambda is only closed over "this"; we should be building a per-object cache that ensures that the delegate is only allocated once per instance and then re-used every time. Also, I would be surprised that the cost of allocating the delegate -- once -- is large compared to the cost of calling ToList. The memory allocator is extremely fast compared to ToList.

Comment: Seems so... Because when I look at decompiled code (using Reflector here ok) I can see that manual loops only use compiler generated enumerator/iterator, but using lambda creates `Func<>`... I've been buffed with lambdas lately. Many times so I'm testing each call to make sure I'm not degrading performance whenever I'm writing performance critical code that uses lambdas. They're so unpredictable... Even this one that doesn't use free variables seems to be slow.